Is there a way, an user, using a looker dashboard, can select himself which measures to be shown on a table?
I'm developing a Looker dashboard, and I'm adding a tile which is a table with several measures and with the date dimension.
I want to know if there's an option where the user can select which measures want to be shown, or if I can hide them and the user can unhide them using the dashboard, so that by default, the users doesn't see them all.
I haven't found a way yet.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
